# create a custom UISegmentControl like

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

[image]

How can I create a UISegmentControl like in the image, What would be the easiest way to implement this?

It would be scrollable segments.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by scrollable segements? Do you want the Custom UISegment to be scrollable?

Comment: I meant, segment views can be scrollable. Scrolling thing isn't very important I can work it myself. I'm not sure how the segments have spaces between them in the image and doubt is it even segmented control or what ?

Comment: Use `UICollectionView` with `interItemSpacing` and change background colors/view depending on if its the selected index. I'm not sure if this is possible at all using `UISegmentControl`

Comment: https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit is a very handy library for your requirement.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl

Answer (score 1):

Put Three UIButton Use as a SegmentControll. its very simple way to do.

Comment: Do you have any examples for me to check out please.